# is it possible to achieve 1000C temperature in a cabin?

Tags: chemical-engineering, heating-systems, chemistry

is it possible that if i have a cabin which is insulated from outside but is built with some sort of material like copper and there is a heating element of sort which is providing 100C constantly but because room is totally insulated and shut can the temperature goes upto 1000C or not ?
if it is what kind of material can be used other can copper ?

Comment: define "totally insulated"?what material? thickness...

Comment: Insulated by thick layers of mud, from every side and thickness of mud around the cabin would be at least 9 inch.

Comment: The internal temperature will stabilise when the energy input is equal to the energy losses from the outside of your cabin : top, bottom and sides...

Comment: Any particular material which losses less energy to outside meaning more and more heating should be inside?

Comment: as for "totally insulated", no such thing as perfect insulator. You could look into Aerogel, which is incredibly efficient as insulator, but even it has its limits.

Comment: What you want isn't called a "cabin".  Look up "oven".

Answer (score 3):

If the heating element is constantly at 100°C, there is no way it can cause the room can get warmer than 100°C.

Otherwise, perpetual motion machines would be possible.

If you meant the heating element is providing a constant 100 Watts, then it is possible for the room to get to 1000°C with enough (meaning a lot) of insulation.

Your copper building might weaken to the point of collapse at 1000°C because copper melts at 1083°C.

Comment: Heating element that i am meaning to use is simple pipes and then revolving 100 C water in it just like normal radiators.

Comment: @Davidweb one way to think about this is the 100c heating element would be a cooling element for any room temperature above 100c.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question the way it's asked

> heating element of sort which is providing 100°C constantly but because room is totally insulated and shut can the temperature goes upto 1000°C or not ?

No, this is not possible.  A 100°C heater can't heat its surroundings above 100°C.  Heat will not pass from cold part of the system to hot part of the system.  Heat passes only from a hotter to a colder system.  [First law of thermodynamics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics#First_law)